# spring form processing - redirecting success view

Tags: spring-mvc

In my spring application , Am doing form processing using SimpleFormController. Does any one know , how to redirect the successView to another resource (URI) ..?

below is my configuration ,

`<bean name="/one.htm" class="aaaaa.Bbbbbbbbb" >`

```
    `<property name="commandClass" value="abc.Def"/>`
    `<property name="formView" value="one"/>`
    `<property name="successView" value="two.htm"/>`
    `<property name="validator" ref="loginValidator"/>`
```

`</bean>`

`<bean name="/two.htm" class="xxxx.yyyy.Zzzzz" />`

`<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">`

```
    `<property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>`
    `<property name="prefix" value="/"/>`
    `<property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>`
```

`</bean>`

I want , the success view should go to **/two.htm** . but it searches **/two.jsp** .
What could be the reason for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `redirect:` prefix:

```
<property name="successView" value="redirect:/two.htm"/>
```

**See also:**

- [15.5.3.2 The redirect: prefix](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-redirecting-redirect-prefix)